# I am having problems understanding this code that I was looking at

Tags: vb.net

I was looking at some connect 4 code and wondered what this was used for, I dont understand the use.

I have looked online to see what it could mean but have not been able to find anything.

```
Public Class PanelBox  
    Inherits Panel 

    Sub New() 
        Me.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle 
    End Sub 

    Private _used As Boolean 

    Public Property Used() As Boolean 
        Get 
            Return _used 
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean) 
            used = value 
        End Set 
    End Property 
End Class
```

Comment: It's a custom control, derived to the .Net Panel control, with a single border line. It also has a custom public property, `Used`, which could be simply defined as `Public Property Used As Boolean` (auto-property, without backing field), from what is show here. Nothing more.

Comment: @Jimi That should be an answer :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean the question should be flagged to be closed :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom control made with a panel which has a border. A square or a rectangle, if you will.

It has a boolean to know if it's used or not.

As it's a connect-four related control, I guess that it must be one of the "spots" in the connect-four panel. One could use an array of those and place them in a grid to "draw" a connect-four panel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a user control / custom control, `Inherits Panel`.  It has a `Used` property most likely for other code to read or know if the control has been loaded and is currently being Used within the scope of that app it's in